# Highchart is not working when I am fetching the axis values from database

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api, highcharts

I am using ASP .Net web api to fetch the data from the database, And trying to make a graph of the derived data , using Highchart. When I am giving the axis values in the form:

```
    xAxis: {
                categories:["Sabab","Sunjare","Ety"]
            },

 series: [{
             data: [20,30,40]
         }]
```

it is working fine. But when I am initializing the categories of xAxis and data of series , by the data , derived from the database, no graph is formed then.
Here is the angular controller code.

```
app.controller('chartController', function ($scope,chartService) {



    loadStudentName();

    function loadStudentName() {
        var promiseget = chartService.getStudentName();

        promiseget.then(function (p1) { $scope.StudentNames = p1.data },
            function (errorP1) {
                alert("Error Occurred");
            });
    }


    loadTotalMarks();

    function loadTotalMarks() {
        var promiseget = chartService.getTotalMarks();

        promiseget.then(function (p1) { $scope.TotalMarks = p1.data },
            function (errorP1) {
                alert("Error occured");
            }
        );
    }


    Highcharts.chart('container', {
        chart: {
            type: 'column'
        },

        xAxis: {
            categories:$scope.StudentNames
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text:"Marks"
            },

        },


        series: [{
            name: "Marks",
            data: $scope.TotalMarks
        }]
    });



});
```

The `$scope.StudentNames` is populated with `["Ety","Sabab","Sunjare","Sadia"]` from the database and `$scope.TotalMarks` is populated with `[393,390,394,341]` from the database, but yet the graph is not formed.

Comment: Do you get any error messages? Are you sure that the data from the database is not wrapped in quotes? Doing a `console.log($scope.TotalMarks)` should help, to make sure

Comment: Array(4) [ "Ety", "Sabab", "Sunjare", "Sadia" ] , this is showing for console.log($scope.StudentNames) and  Array(4) [ 393, 390, 394, 341 ] is showing for console.log($scope.TotalMarks)  in the console. And I do not get any error message @ewolden

Comment: The reason of this issue might be that `$scope.TotalMarks` and `$scope.StudentNames` aren't initialized in the time when the chart is created (the data is fetched asynchronously). You can try creating the chart without the data & categories and do `Chart.update()` (https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Chart#update) in the callbacks that you pass as arguments to `promiseget.then`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to refresh your highcharts after data is updated, either:

1. put a watch on both of your data objects and do chart.redraw(); if
   it changes
2. call redraw method after after you update your data
   inside of promise.

I recommend creating a directive that takes highchart config object and watches that for changes and then redraws the chart, that way you can reuse it.